# Vaadin SQLContainer Reference - how to implement foreign key relation?

Tags: sql, vaadin

I don't get it how I can implement an foreign-key relationship with SQLContainer from Vaadin. 
Let's assume I have two tables:

1. BOOK with attributes *title* and *author_id*
2. AUTHOR with attributes *id_author, first_name* and *last_name*

Of coure BOOK.author_id is referencing to AUTHOR.id
I already created a MySQL-DB with all necessary constraints. Furthermore I created containers and filled them like follows:

```
private static void initContainers() {
    try {
        /* TableQuery and SQLContainer for book -table */
        TableQuery q1 = new TableQuery("book", connectionPool);
        bookContainer = new SQLContainer(q1);

        /* TableQuery and SQLContainer for author -table */
        TableQuery q2 = new TableQuery("author", connectionPool);
        authorContainer = new SQLContainer(q2);


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean addBook(Book book) {
    Object id_author = authorContainer.addItem();
    authorContainer.getContainerProperty(id_author,  "first_name").setValue(book.getAuthor().getFirstName());
    authorContainer.getContainerProperty(id_author, "last_name").setValue(book.getAuthor().getLastName());      

    Object id = bookContainer.addItem();   
    bookContainer.getContainerProperty(id, "title").setValue(book.getTitle());         

//HERE IS MY TRY FOR ADDING THE REFERENCE (FOREIGN KEY RELATION)
    bookContainer.addReference(authorContainer, "author_id", "id_author");         
    authorContainer.setReferencedItem("id_author", "author_id", bookContainer);
    bookContainer.getContainerProperty(id, "author").setValue(bookContainer.getReferencedItem("id_author", authorContainer)); 

    try {
        authorContainer.commit();
        bookContainer.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here? I also tried committing the author-container before adding the reference, but that did not work either.

I always get a NullPointerException at *bookContainer.getReferencedItem("id_author", authorContainer)*

Answer (score 1):

try `authorContainer.getReferencedItem("id_author", bookContainer)`